# Audio flow - connections

Tags: audio

is there a way to connect output sound from an app to input sound to another?

I want to play on [sonobus](https://www.sonobus.net/), but I would like to equalize first my instrument, may be through garageband for example.

On Linux exists qjackctl that allows audio connections flows:

[image]

I see some third party software like [loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/), but I don't know if exists something standard or out of the box.

Please, be nice, my first question here.

Comment: Sonobus says it can use AU, VST & AAX plugins - so you can do it all without having to pipe anywhere else. Wiring outputs to inputs is not easy even with Loopback [intercepting a set of inputs or outputs is a different task]. There's a structure known as [ReWire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReWire_\(software_protocol\)) for inter-app audio comms, but I haven't used that in a long time.

Comment: Done. Welcome..

Comment: I don't know either, sorry. I'm a long-time user of Cubase [since the mid 1980's ;)) & have a reasonable working knowledge of audio in general on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sonobus](https://www.sonobus.net) says it can use AU, VST & AAX plugins - so you can do it all without having to pipe anywhere else.

Wiring outputs to inputs is not easy even with [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/). [Intercepting a set of inputs or outputs is a different task & much simpler to do].

There's a structure known as [ReWire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReWire_(software_protocol)) for inter-app audio comms, but I haven't used that in a long time.